# Excel Macro to find a cell based on matching two values (Row/Column) and replace value in cell

Tags: excel, indexing, replace, match

I am having some trouble trying to find a solution to an issue I have. I have two excel sheets that I would like to find or index values from one sheet to the other and then replace the value of the cell after locating the cell.

I think maybe a better way to picture is that I have a excel sheet "Data1" that consists of three columns with rows of data.

Example of Sheet 1:

```
      A          B                c
1 | Header 1 | Header 2       | Header 3 |
2 | -------- | -------------- |----------|
3 | 123456   | AABB           |12AB12AB  |
4 | 678910   | BBCC           |34CD34CD  |
```

I have a second Excel Sheet "Data2" that consists of multiple columns and rows of data.

Example Sheet "Data2":

```
      A         B            C          D         E
1 | Header1  | BBCC       | CCDD     | AABB    | EEFF    |
2 | -------- | -----------|----------|---------|---------|
3 | 123456   | ValueX     | ValueY   |  ValueZ | ValueB  |
4 | 678910   | ValueXX    | ValueXY  | ValueYY | ValueZZ |
```

What I would like to do is run a macro:

To first, match the value A3 (123456) in Sheet "Data1" to the same value in Column A from Sheet "Data2"

Second, match the value B3 (AABB) in Sheet "Data1" to the same value in Row 1 from Sheet "Data2"

Third, replace the value in the corresponding cell with the value from Sheet "Data1" cell C3.

Then, Loop and replace all cells until the rows of data from Sheet "Data1" end.

The Values in Sheet "Data2" should then change to look like:

```
       A         B            C          D          E
1 | Header1  | BBCC       | CCDD     | AABB     | EEFF    |
2 | -------- | -----------|----------|----------|---------|
3 | 123456   | ValueX     | ValueY   | 12AB12AB | ValueB  |
4 | 678910   | 34CD34CD   | ValueXY  | ValueYY  | ValueZZ |
```

Please let me know what you think and I hope I laid out the requirements as simple as possible. Thank you for your time and support to help me work this solution. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

IF your version of Excel supports `XLOOKUP` then you can set up Sheet "Data3" with the same column and row headers and use this functions for the data cells.

```
=XLOOKUP($A3&B$1,Data1!$A$3:$A$4&Data1!$B$3:$B$4,Data1!$C$3:$C$4,Data2!B3)
```

It takes the data in data2 and overwrites it with the data from data1 if there is a match.

[image: Sample Solution]

[More on XLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929)